# I am getting unnecessary blank line when trying to type text on mouse focus

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am using a multiline text box in which I can type messages ether by continuously typing a message or type text while pressing enter key few times.

So my input might look like this:

```
This is some text
this is come other text
and some other text
```

And by using `SendKeys.Send(txtText.Text + "{enter}");` my output looks like:

```
This is some text

this is come other text

and some other text
```

How can I delete that unnecessary new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
  string text=txtText.Text;
  txtText.Text=string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                    text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```